# Regex com JavaScript - Pegando apenas uma parte da String

Tags: javascript, regex

Digamos que tenho a seguinte string:

```
str = "http://www.google.com/joao.pedro?a=b";
```

Ai eu quero pegar apenas o *joao.pedro* usando **JavaScript**.

Acredito que da para fazer com **Regex** de alguma forma, alguém pode me ajudar como?

Eu pensei em algo como, usar esta expressão regular:

```
(http://www.google.com/)([\d\w\.]+)
```

E pegar o valor que estaria entre o segundo parênteses. No PHP dá para fazer algo parecido com isso usando a função `preg_match`, mas e no JavaScript?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Quero extrair o nome que está apos o .com/ e antes do ?..., enfim, acho que estou achando a solução aqui e já posto na Stack.

Comment: Veja: https://jsbin.com/wesapo/edit?js,console

Comment: Isso, eu usei a função match ao inves dessa, mas o resultado é o mesmo. Veja minha resposta, se eu escrevi algo errado por favor me indique para corrigir, ou poste uma sua que marcarei como melhor resposta, visto que soluciona meu caso.

Comment: Não precisa de regex. Se quer manipular URL's, use o objeto `URL`. No caso, ficaria `new URL("http://www.google.com/joao.pedro?a=b").pathname.slice(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso, para solução precisa usar a função match.

Essa função retornará um array com as ocorrências da expressão regular.

Nesta aplicação:

```
string = "http://www.google.com/joao.pedro?a=b";
a = string.match(/(http:\/\/www\.google\.com\/)([\d\w\.]+)/);
```

a retorna um array:

```
Array [ "http://www.google.com/joao.pedro", "http://www.google.com/", "joao.pedro" ]
```

Veja que a primeira ocorrência é o corpo inteiro da string, e as subsequentes seriam as ocorrencias que a expressão regular encontrou na string.

Answer (score 1):

Bem simples e nao precisa de regex:

```
var str = "http://www.google.com/joao.pedro?a=b/";
var valor= str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".com/")+5,str.lastIndexOf("?"));
```

Resultado: `joao.pedro`

explicacao `".com/"` ou somente `"/"`, a barra pode aparecer no final do link e o codio teria que ter validacoes para evitar ou tratar a string o `+5` é para remover o .com/ do resultado

Comment: e se for `.com.br`?

Comment: pode ser .tr, .fr, .es... isso pode ser validado com contains ".br/" mesma coisa precisa ser feita se fizer uso do regex

Comment: enumeraria um por um? e se terminar em `?a=com`?

Comment: para primeira pergunta sim, para segunda pergunta: mas ja terminar com isso nao? @AndreFigueiredo

Answer (score 0):

#### A. Com RegExp

Uma entre as infinitas (ie: `.*` x *Infinito*) possibilidades, uma genérica é:

```
str.match(/^.*(:\/\/)*.*\/(.*)[#\?].*/)[2]
```

que pode ser traduzida em a partir do início (`^`), qualquer cadeia de caracteres 0-"Infinito" (`.*`), exceto por e seguida por `(://)` (aka protocolo), cadeira de caracteres seguida de `/` (domínio), cadeia de caracteres (caminho - o que queremos), cadeia de caracteres iniciada por `?` (querystring) ou `#` (hash location).

#### B. Sem RegExp

1. Particionando String - versão de "uma linha":

   ```
   (((str
     .split('://')[1] || '')
     .split('/')[1] || '')
     .split('?')[0] || '')
     .split('#')[0]
   ```
2. Usando [`HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils):

   ```
   var a = document.createElement('a')
   a.href="http://www.google.com/joao.pedro?a=b"
   a.pathname.substring(1)
   ```

---

* Não estou levando em conta outras partes URI pouco usadas na Web, como usuário e senha.

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = /[a-z]\\/([\w.]+)/g;

const rege = (text) => {
let user = regex.exec(text);
 return hue[1];
}

console.log(
  rege("http://www.google.com/joao.pedro?a=b")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Meu regex ficou assim:

```
   /(\w+\.\w+)(?=\?)/
```

1. `(\w+\.\w+)` Procure por um texto que tenha um `.` seguido por um texto.
2. `(?=\?)` use positive lookahead, ou seja, olhando pra frente procure por `?`

<sup>[Funcionando em regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OdLSPi/1)</sup>